# Are there automatic boarding pass gates at Malpensa airport's Terminal 1?

Tags: tickets, airports, italy, milan, mxp

I'm going to accompany a friend in March from Linate to Malpensa airport, and wonder if terminal 1 at Malpensa has automatic boarding pass gates? If it does, I can sneak up behind him and will accompany him airside while he's waiting for the connecting flight.

NB: this is not a question about the *legality* of sneaking into airside, but essentially whether it's *possible* at that terminal.

Comment: What's your plan for getting out again afterwards? Most people leave departures airside by getting on a plane...

Comment: @user568458 arrivals and departures are usually mixed for Schengen flights

Comment: @JonathanReez And at several major ones, such as MUC and ZRH, you can even enter the non-Schengen area and then exit

Comment: You realize there's likely to be surveillance video on the gates, right?

Comment: @mkennedy Yes, though at least at ZRH it's never been an issue for me

Comment: Maybe you should just dress up like a ninja and crawl through the air conditioning ducts instead?

Comment: [Policy on questions about how to break the law](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1405/how-should-questions-answers-on-how-to-do-something-illegal-be-treated)

Comment: MXP has automatic gates. If my memory serves me well these are guarded by two security officers. I would never think of sneaking my way into the airport security checks area for a number of reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having an hard time answering this one, because as far as I remember Malpensa's layout (of both terminals) I don't see a way an automatic boarding gate can help you.

In Malpensa (well...as far as I can remember, in all the European airports I've been) the first barrier you hit is security control, and you can pass it only with a valid boarding pass: good luck squeezing behind your friend so that the guards will not notice you :-D

---

**Editing** in more details because I'm not sure I've understood the question enough to have given a proper answer.

Malpensa T1 departure's main area, the first you walk in from outside, is a huge hall in front of the runways, where you can wander freely, take a coffe, buy a ticket, watch planes, go upstair for an hamburger at <s>McDowell</s> McDonald's, use toilette, check-in, and so on.

Next, to go somewhere else, you have to queue at security: if you can sneak past them...you are a ninja.

---

Side note: T2 departures is exactly the same, apart from being a small and dark hall where the only thing you can do is to queue for security.

Comment: At ZRH I often do plane-spotting in the non-Schengen area, and sneak up behind any random passenger. After that, no one cares about the boarding pass - only the automatic gate

Comment: Does security ask to see your boarding pass though? At least in Prague Airport you can enter the Schengen area's security check without a real person seeing your boarding pass.

Comment: @JonathanReez At ZRH? Never, once you're through the gate you're golden